# PHP finding second occurrence of a word in array using array_search

Tags: php

Following code will split a sentence and tell me first occurrence of the word orange. Can you please tell me if it's possible to find the second occurrence of the word orange using a php library function. I could do this by using a `for loop,` just wondering if `array_search` library function could do this?

```
$sentence = "apple orange grapes mango orange banana orange";
$wordarray = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $sentence); //split by space and comma
$img_pos = array_search('orange', $wordarray);//To get the position of orange
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_keys()` takes a search parameter, so just get the keys for the value you want and check for the second one (`[1]`):

```
$img_pos = array_keys($wordarray, 'orange');
print_r($img_pos);
echo $img_pos[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with some kind of for loop similar to this:

```
$instance = 1;
for($start=1; $start=2;$start++)
{
    if($instance == 2)
    {
        // second instance
    }
    else
    {
        // not second (first or 3+)
    }
}
```

Hopefully this brings you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

From the [array_search() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

"If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead."

So, this should work:

```
$keys = array_keys($wordarray, "orange");
$img_pos = $keys[1];
print $img_pos;
```

Comment: It won't be `end()` that would be the third.  It would be `$img_pos[1]`